# SocketStream equivalent for .Net

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, xmpp

I am trying to write and read xml from a Socket but Im not sure how to do this with .Net. A SocketStream looks like an easy way to do this but Im not trying to build an application for Windows 8 or Windows phone. If someone could share some insight or maybe some code snippits on how to do the equivalent with .Net I would greatly appreciate it.

```
        private const string MESSAGE_SERVER_URL = "xmpp.messenger.live.com";
        private const string MESSAGE_SERVER_PORT = "5222";

        /// <summary>
        /// login into live message server
        /// </summary>

        private async void LoginXMPPServer(string access)
        {
            using (StreamSocket client = new StreamSocket())
            {
                // connect to server
                await client.ConnectAsync(new HostName(MESSAGE_SERVER_URL), MESSAGE_SERVER_PORT);
                DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(client.OutputStream);
                DataReader reader = new DataReader(client.InputStream);
                reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;

                //initialize a stream
                string head = "<?xml version='1.0'?>" +
                    "<stream:stream " +
                    "to='messenger.live.com' " +
                    "xmlns='jabber:client' " +
                    "xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' " +
                    "version='1.0'>";
                await SendMessage(head, writer);

                string reply = await ReadReplay(reader);
                if (reply.Contains("stream:error"))
                    return;
             }
       }
```

Comment: I have edited your question and replaced the `[WPF]` tag by the `[.Net ]` tag, because this doesn't really have anything to do with WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example taken from [.net SendFile method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx0a40c2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
// Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
IPAddress  ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 11000);

// Create a TCP socket.
Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

// Connect the socket to the remote endpoint.
client.Connect(ipEndPoint);

// There is a text file test.txt located in the root directory. 
string fileName = "C:\\test.txt";

// Send file fileName to remote device
Console.WriteLine("Sending {0} to the host.", fileName);
client.SendFile(fileName);

// Release the socket.
client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
client.Close();
```